# Boss accidentally shared confidental company documents, what to do?

Tags: secrecy

It is an automatic synchronization app. On its server side, it has multiple repositories, between them at least one for which I shouldn't have any access.

After I've understood what is going on, I killed the synchronization process on the spot and deleted my whole local directory structure.

Now the problem is that it is not enough, because I can't prove it, that I didn't make a secret copy from that.

I think also have to minimize any suspection that maybe I misused it.

Now the problem is that I don't have any way to prove that.

I think the best would be to minimize any possible suspiction in the future, if I simply don't do anything, and live without the document share until some days long. After that, the problem will be surely, and silently self-solved.

The boss already knows the mistake (my co-workers also contacted him on the spot), and knowing that he knows it, I didn't contact him.

Ext: Now I contacted him, I wrote him a single sentence: "Hello, I killed the syncing app and deleted my whole local repo."

Ext2: Now another boss surprisingly visited my PC and I showed him that I really deleted/killed everything. He seemed satisfied.

Comment: If you are completely honest about what happened, shouldn't it be on your management to prove that you did copy a secret document, rather than it being on you to prove you didn't?

Comment: @JonK I trust the company, but I have a big fear that maybe it doesn't trust me. And I can't prove that I really didn't do any bad.

Comment: @JonK Nothing about others, only own company, but these were really only for the eyes of top-leaders.

Comment: wait - what? I'm not sure who did what here and what you fear. Did the boss share confidential stuff or did you?

Comment: I was contemplating editing this but I can't actually tell what the problem is. What is your core question?

Comment: @Lilienthal The question was, what is the right thing to do, focusing to my most obvious goal to somehow make the chances in the eyes of the bosses, that I misused the information, as low as possible.

Comment: @NKCampbell The boss reconfigured something in a company share. It was accidentally misconfigured. This resulted that docs were copied into the hard drive of all employee what is only for the eyes of the management. I stopped the file synchron and deleted everything, but I can't prove for sure that I didn't misuse them on some way (f.e. by making a private copy from them before the deletion).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Communicate clearly in writing to your boss and any other relevant personnel (e.g. anyone else involved and if you have someone in charge of information security) exactly what happened and what action you took.  Not just a one line email but a self contained description of the whole incident:

> Dear Boss,
>
> Just to recap, when I was working on the repository last night, I noticed that XYZ folder had been inadvertantly shared with me.
>
> I immediately stopped the process, and deleted all local files from my PC.
>
> [Your boss] has also visited and confirmed that everything is deleted.
>
> Is there anything else I need to do to verify that everything is ok?
>
> Thanks,
> me.

That way there is a clear written record of what happened.  Your transparency about the event will help calm any fears, and will serve as evidence should any concerns arise in the future.

I think you probably don't need to worry too much, though. At most workplaces, anyway, this wouldn't be such a big deal (at least not in terms of raising suspicion about you).

**Update:** If you have someone in charge of information security, or any policy that requires reporting on incidents, I think it's important that you inform others of what happened.  However, if these other parties get surprised with the notice that your boss caused a security breach, that may put your boss in an awkward place.  So, if you aren't sure anyone else knows about it, it's a good idea to give your boss a heads up before sending that email (as recommended by nvoigt in the comments).  In this case, I don't think it applies, since your boss's boss already knows.

Comment: Getting the security people involved without prior knowledge of your boss might be "correct" but might also get you in trouble with your boss. Just saying.

Comment: Oh, thank you, this is what I had to do, but the events happened faster :-) Now I think were are already after the event, and there is few to do. I can only hope that they believe me.

Comment: @nvoigt, that's a fair point.  But if your boss messed up and is trying to keep it secret, not communicating this to anyone other than your boss might be a risk for you, as well.  In this case, the boss's boss knows already, so it's probably a moot point.

Comment: @dan1111 A good middle way might be to give said boss a head's up saying "hey, according to our security guidelines, I need to report this too X, do you want to be on CC?" This gives the boss time to actually come out with it *first* instead of the impression that his underling is ratting him out. Might save the boss' reputation to report it in a favorable way and might save the underling a lot of flak from the boss feeling "reported to Security".

Comment: @nvoigt very good point.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your boss has the security clearance and you don't, ask you boss what to do. *He* should know the proper procedures, that should be part of his clearance.

There is not much you could do and doing something wrong might make it worse. So ask for advice and wait for orders.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Nothing really hardcore material, but it would be far enough for a fire-on-the-spot if I had misused it. Furthermore, I don't have any reason to not trust the company, but it is not surely so vice versa. My only goal is to somehow prove that I really deleted everything, but this I can't do.

Answer (score 1):

> "Hello, I killed the syncing app and deleted my whole local repo."

You didn't say anything more. He has no idea whether what you did was an accident or not. You make it sound like it was on purpose.

Clarify that the incident was an accident and ask him how to proceed. He's your boss so you should tell him what happens when something happens that's not suppose to happen, regardless of whether you think he knows it or he doesn't. You then ask him how to proceed. You don't make assumptions, you don't make decisions, if it's not in your job description.

Don't try to hide anything, simply ask your boss what to do. You're going to make your live a living hell and one day make a massive cover up mistake that will blow in your face if you never ask your boss what to do when something wrong happens.

If you suspect your boss of doing wrongdoings related to this, you can try to contact HR or talk to a lawyer.

**EDIT**

As long as you tell them everything you know they can't accuse you of any intentional wrongdoings without proof. The moment you decide to not tell them something that's when you can be held accountable for your actions.

Comment: I don't suspect they do anything wrong, but I fear greatly that they don't believe that I really deleted it.

Comment: It doesn't matter what they believe. As long as you tell them everything you know they can't accuse you of anything. The moment you decide to not tell them something that's when you can be held accountable for your actions.